# Issues with Exchange Server 2007 with one DC being down

Tags: exchange-2007, active-directory, domain-controller

We have Exchange Server and two domain controllers.  The problem is that we have one of the domain controllers down due to some hardware failures, but my exchange is not working with my second domain controller.  Do we need to any modifications on exchange?  What steps do we need to follow in order for our farm to be happy?

Note :- DNS has been configured on Both the servers.

Comment: By the way - "Dear Support" is a bad idea for a salutation on this site. We're not a support desk. This site is a way for professionals to ask questions to each other.

Comment: @mfinni you can always edit it ;)

Comment: @l0c0b0x - sure, and I see you did. But I'm trying to educate a new user on the norms, and an edit might be overlooked.

Answer (score 9):

Are both domain controllers configured as global catalogs? I'm guessing that the one that was down was your only GC. Assuming that you have a single domain and a single site, just make them both GCs, that's going to be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I always make my DCs Global Catalogs; with very few exceptions it makes sense for most (if not all) of your DCs to have a copy of the entire catalog.

Answer (score 2):

You can check what DCs that Exchange is using by:

**Manager**:  Server Configuration -> Client Access, right click on a CA server, go to properties. On the System Settings tab will be the list of what DC/GC servers it is using.

**Powershell**:  get-exchangeservers $HubCAName -status |select CurrentDomainControllers |fl

If your other DC is not in that list, you'll want to check the Application event-log on your CA server. The event ID is 2080 and should occur every 15 minutes. This lists the AD discovery process Exchange follows. For decoding what these events mean [KB316300](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=316300) describes it. This may yield clues as to why the other DC isn't being considered.

Answer (score 0):

This redundancy would be determined by examining the FSMO roles of your active directory system.

Take a look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/mempson/archive/2007/11/08/how-to-find-out-who-has-your-fsmo-roles.aspx for a complete reference guide which will be a great resource.

Comment: Please tell me what FSMO roles you think Exchange depends on.

Comment: Actions of operation and functionality.  You might not be able to change passwords, create new distribution groups, add new users.  If all remains the same then none.  But since it ties into active directory I would most specifically count on having availability of the Infrastructure Master & PDC Emulator , 2 out of the 5 FSMO roles available.

Comment: Nick - provide documentation that loss of the FSMO roles would stop Exchange entirely, which is what the OP is asking for. Also, none of those operations are isolated to Exchange, or even depend on FSMO roles in all cases. Password changes do not depend on PDCe (instant notifications to other DCs do though, to my recall.) Infrastructure master - wrong. Nothing to do with exchange. New user and groups will depend on DCs having a local RID pool, and if that pool is exhausted and the RID master is down there could be a problem.

Comment: I don't think this is helping address the question posted or concerning to open discussion, a distraction I am accepting my -1 since I have stopped reading after seeing the word OP.  Good day.

Comment: Nick - I'm happy to be educated if I'm wrong.

Comment: lets chat maybe on Friday.  There is a lot of and energy and some enhanced by caffeine in the office today, operations are running wild.  I'll ping you at the end of the week, have a good one. -Nick